# Dynamically set Maven Surefire JVM classpath

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to add the JVM classpath argument when running our Maven unit tests by adding the following maven arguments, with "dir" replaced by my desired clasaspath.

> MAVEN_OPTS = -cp "dir"

This correctly then get's added to the Java arguments

Yet my "dir" is never correctly added to the classpath. 
The desired file in the classpath is never found, and is always missing when printing out classpath with

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between a JVM run by Maven and the JVM in use when running your tests.

The surefire plugin will spawn its own JVM to run your test case(s). By default, it will include the following on that JVM's classpath:

- Your project's classes directory
- Your project's test-classes directory
- Your project's dependencies.

If I have understood your question correctly then you want to add another directory to the classpath for the JVM which is running your test(s). If so, then you can add additional classpath entry like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <configuration>
      <additionalClasspathElements>
        <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/your/additional/directory</additionalClasspathElement>
      </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More details [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html).

If you want to dynamically change the classpath used by the surefire JVM via a command line parameter (as your mention of MAVEN_OPTS implies) then you could define an `additionalClasspathElement` like this ...

```
<additionalClasspathElement>${additionalClasspathDir}</additionalClasspathElement>
```

... and then invoke Maven like this:

```
mvn test -DadditionalClasspathDir=path/to/your/additional/directory
```

Comment: Is there any method adding variables to those paths, in the form if maven ops? We would rather not have hard coded paths in our pom file

Comment: I have updated my answer to address the requirement to dynamically change the classpath used by the surefire plugin. The surefire plugin is clear about how it composes its classpath and if your desired dir is not already on the project's classpath and cannot be added to it (using the [Maven Build Helper Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) for example) then using `additionalClasspathElements` is your only option.

Comment: That worked, just had to add the -D prefix to the variable

Comment: mvn test -DadditionalClasspathDir=path/to/your/additional/directory worked perfectly! Thanks!